# How to add custom webpart section under SharePoint modern page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, sitepages, collapsible-sections

I need to add a custom design layout under SharePoint online modern page.

By default, SharePoint provides six types of layouts marked with a red border in the below image.

I need to add my custom layout under that red markerd area. Is there any solution for the same?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible in SharePoint online modern experience.

SharePoint online does not allow us to create a custom layout for modern page sections.

**Documentation**: [Add sections and columns on a SharePoint modern page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-sections-and-columns-on-a-sharepoint-modern-page-fc491eb4-f733-4825-8fe2-e1ed80bd0899)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Can I add a vertical section which the same as One-third left? I need to add a vertical sidebar on the left side of the SharePoint modern page.

Comment: Vertical sections are currently available only on the right side of the page. In a narrow browser window, a vertical section can be moved to the bottom or at the top of the page.

Comment: Only languages with Right-to-left read script (like Arabic) can have vertical section at the left side of screen/browser.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Appreciate your help.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped you!